# Not able to understand mutate

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and learnt lots of R functions but not able to comprehend the mutate the data frame. Since I am pursuing a course Introduction to Probability and Data at Coursera where I am not able to solve a question, Recently I came across one of the exercises where it was asked to the mutate the data frame, which is as follows

Suppose you define a flight to be "on time" if it gets to the destination on time or earlier than expected, regardless of any departure delays. Mutate the data frame to create a new variable called `arr_type` with levels `"on time"` and `"delayed"` based on this definition. Then, determine the on-time arrival percentage based on whether the flight departed on time or not. What proportion of flights  that 
were `"delayed"` departing arrive `"on time"`?

Please guide me and explain how to comprehend this clause?

Comment: it's a funtion from [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: See: the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works:

```
(df <- data.frame(group=gl(2,2), value=1:4))
#   group value
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     2     3
# 4     2     4
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(avg=mean(value))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: group [2]
# 
#    group value   avg
#   (fctr) (int) (dbl)
# 1      1     1   1.5
# 2      1     2   1.5
# 3      2     3   3.5
# 4      2     4   3.5
```

You can also group by several variables, like `group_by(plane, flight)`. So you should be able to get where you want easily.

Comment: Feel free to add your attempts to your question, too.